# Testcontainers timed out waiting for container port to open, with Elasticsearch docker image

Tags: java, docker, elasticsearch, spring-boot-maven-plugin, testcontainers

I'm learning Spring Data Elasticsearch and Testcontainers. As a first step, I'm trying to run the docker image for Elasticsearch with Testcontainers, but I just spent a whole day yet cannot get it working.

Here is the test class body:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

@Testcontainers
public class TestcontainersTest {
    // container {
    @Container
    public GenericContainer container = new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("elasticsearch:7.6.2"))
            .withExposedPorts(9200)
            .withCommand("--name=esTest -e \"discovery.type=single-node\"");
//    public GenericContainer container = new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("redis:5.0.3-alpine"))
//            .withExposedPorts(6379);

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        String address = container.getHost();
        Integer port = container.getFirstMappedPort();

        // Now we have an address and port for Redis, no matter where it is running
//        underTest = new RedisBackedCache(address, port);
    }

    @Test
    public void testTest() {
        while (true);
    }
}
```

I set breakpoints for every line in `setUp()` and `testTest()`, but when I run with `Debug testTest()` it just never reaches the lines. (I'm using IntelliJ IDEA btw) It simply failed on starting the docker container, if my understanding is correct.

On the other hand, if I change the commented out part before `setUp`, that is, if I change to use a redis image (as codes in [JUnit 5 Quickstart](https://www.testcontainers.org/quickstart/junit_5_quickstart/) from the official Testcontainers webpage), things go smoothly and I can stop at the breakpoint and check that the container is running with `docker ps`:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
0db5ae6e1129        redis:5.0.3-alpine          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:32817->6379/tcp   wizardly_euler
31620f900e18        testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.0   "/app"                   8 seconds ago       Up 7 seconds        0.0.0.0:32816->8080/tcp   testcontainers-ryuk-e84d6102-4e8c-4c80-bfc7-5deb55864526
```

I tried to dig a little bit into the error message produced after Elasticsearch container attempt. It is very long, and from which I find the following:

```
18:09:03.133 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.containers.ExecInContainerPattern - /determined_brown: Running "exec" command: /bin/sh -c true &&  (cat /proc/net/tcp* | awk '{print $2}' | grep -i ':0*23f0' || nc -vz -w 1 localhost 9200 || /bin/bash -c '</dev/tcp/localhost/9200')
18:09:03.133 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: 2cb002a7b520fe9b2f5771088e028b34bf4b58bb041a3d6abb5e200cf4c1fc6e,<null>,true,true,<null>,<null>,<null>,{/bin/sh,-c,true &&  (cat /proc/net/tcp* | awk '{print $2}' | grep -i ':0*23f0' || nc -vz -w 1 localhost 9200 || /bin/bash -c '</dev/tcp/localhost/9200')},<null>,<null>
18:09:04.153 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.containers.ExecInContainerPattern - /determined_brown: Running "exec" command: /bin/sh -c true &&  (cat /proc/net/tcp* | awk '{print $2}' | grep -i ':0*23f0' || nc -vz -w 1 localhost 9200 || /bin/bash -c '</dev/tcp/localhost/9200')
18:09:04.153 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: 2cb002a7b520fe9b2f5771088e028b34bf4b58bb041a3d6abb5e200cf4c1fc6e,<null>,true,true,<null>,<null>,<null>,{/bin/sh,-c,true &&  (cat /proc/net/tcp* | awk '{print $2}' | grep -i ':0*23f0' || nc -vz -w 1 localhost 9200 || /bin/bash -c '</dev/tcp/localhost/9200')},<null>,<null>
18:09:05.162 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.containers.ExecInContainerPattern - /determined_brown: Running "exec" command: /bin/sh -c true &&  (cat /proc/net/tcp* | awk '{print $2}' | grep -i ':0*23f0' || nc -vz -w 1 localhost 9200 || /bin/bash -c '</dev/tcp/localhost/9200')
18:09:05.163 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: 2cb002a7b520fe9b2f5771088e028b34bf4b58bb041a3d6abb5e200cf4c1fc6e,<null>,true,true,<null>,<null>,<null>,{/bin/sh,-c,true &&  (cat /proc/net/tcp* | awk '{print $2}' | grep -i ':0*23f0' || nc -vz -w 1 localhost 9200 || /bin/bash -c '</dev/tcp/localhost/9200')},<null>,<null>
```

You see that the first 2 lines repeat 3 times. They actually repeat more than 3 times, as you can tell from the timestamps of the first 2 lines in the error message block below:

```
18:10:01.754 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.containers.ExecInContainerPattern - /determined_brown: Running "exec" command: /bin/sh -c true &&  (cat /proc/net/tcp* | awk '{print $2}' | grep -i ':0*23f0' || nc -vz -w 1 localhost 9200 || /bin/bash -c '</dev/tcp/localhost/9200')
18:10:01.754 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: 2cb002a7b520fe9b2f5771088e028b34bf4b58bb041a3d6abb5e200cf4c1fc6e,<null>,true,true,<null>,<null>,<null>,{/bin/sh,-c,true &&  (cat /proc/net/tcp* | awk '{print $2}' | grep -i ':0*23f0' || nc -vz -w 1 localhost 9200 || /bin/bash -c '</dev/tcp/localhost/9200')},<null>,<null>
18:10:02.093 [main] DEBUG  [elasticsearch:7.6.2] - Wait strategy threw an exception
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for container port to open (localhost ports: [32820] should be listening)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.HostPortWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(HostPortWaitStrategy.java:49)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.AbstractWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(AbstractWaitStrategy.java:35)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.waitUntilContainerStarted(GenericContainer.java:895)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:443)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:328)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:326)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:314)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.start(TestcontainersExtension.java:242)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.access$200(TestcontainersExtension.java:229)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$null$4(TestcontainersExtension.java:82)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$0(ExtensionValuesStore.java:81)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:182)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespaceAwareStore.java:53)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$beforeEach$5(TestcontainersExtension.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:441)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:274)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:952)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:926)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractTask.compute(AbstractTask.java:327)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:746)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:408)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:736)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateParallel(ReduceOps.java:919)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.beforeEach(TestcontainersExtension.java:85)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$1(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:161)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$5(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:197)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:160)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
...
...
...
18:10:02.094 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: 2cb002a7b520fe9b2f5771088e028b34bf4b58bb041a3d6abb5e200cf4c1fc6e,false
18:10:02.094 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.InspectContainerCmdExec - GET: DefaultWebTarget{path=[/containers/2cb002a7b520fe9b2f5771088e028b34bf4b58bb041a3d6abb5e200cf4c1fc6e/json], queryParams={}}
18:10:02.150 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: 2cb002a7b520fe9b2f5771088e028b34bf4b58bb041a3d6abb5e200cf4c1fc6e,false
18:10:02.150 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.InspectContainerCmdExec - GET: DefaultWebTarget{path=[/containers/2cb002a7b520fe9b2f5771088e028b34bf4b58bb041a3d6abb5e200cf4c1fc6e/json], queryParams={}}
18:10:02.156 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: 2cb002a7b520fe9b2f5771088e028b34bf4b58bb041a3d6abb5e200cf4c1fc6e,false
18:10:02.156 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.InspectContainerCmdExec - GET: DefaultWebTarget{path=[/containers/2cb002a7b520fe9b2f5771088e028b34bf4b58bb041a3d6abb5e200cf4c1fc6e/json], queryParams={}}
18:10:02.171 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: 2cb002a7b520fe9b2f5771088e028b34bf4b58bb041a3d6abb5e200cf4c1fc6e,true,true
18:10:02.182 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper - Removed container and associated volume(s): elasticsearch:7.6.2


org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed

    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:333)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:314)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.start(TestcontainersExtension.java:242)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.access$200(TestcontainersExtension.java:229)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$null$4(TestcontainersExtension.java:82)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$0(ExtensionValuesStore.java:81)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:182)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespaceAwareStore.java:53)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$beforeEach$5(TestcontainersExtension.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:441)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:274)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:952)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:926)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractTask.compute(AbstractTask.java:327)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:746)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:408)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:736)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateParallel(ReduceOps.java:919)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.beforeEach(TestcontainersExtension.java:85)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$1(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:161)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$5(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:197)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:160)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:88)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:326)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:500)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:328)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container exited with code 2
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:472)
    ... 85 more


Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53361', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 255
```

The 2 lines repeat for about 1 minute and then timed out. My question is, why? What is going on there? How can I fix this?

If anyone wants to try it out, here is the [repo](https://github.com/Lansorian/elasticsearch-testcontainers). You can just ignore all other files except `src/test/java/tagbangers/eatsample/TestcontainersTest.java`, which is where all the codes and error messages mentioned above happened.

Alternatively, I found that in the official [Spring Data Elasticsearch repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch), in `CONTRIBUTING.adoc` it is said that

> ... Spring Data Elasticsearch uses Testcontainers to start a local running Elasticsearch instance.

But I can't find where and how is that achieved?

Thanks for any help!

Edit:
Solved after I change to use `ElasticsearchContainer` instead of `GenericContainer`, as suggested by the selected answer. Thank you!

Comment: Have you fixed it or do you still need assistance?

Comment: Thank you and yes my problem solves after switching to the Elasticsearch module (thank dadoonet!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change:

```
DockerImageName.parse("elasticsearch:7.6.2")
```

by

```
DockerImageName.parse("docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2")
```

Although the former should redirect to the later...

**EDIT**: the problem has been solved by using the [Elasticsearch module](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/elasticsearch/)?

Comment: The only reason is I didn't notice that there is such a specific module for Elasticsearch. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: The simple change still doesn't make GenericContainer work with Elasticsearch image tho

Comment: Did you try to read the elasticsearch logs while it is starting? May be it did not finish to start before the time out?

Comment: Maybe, but my problem solves after switching to the Elasticsearch module (thank you!), so I give up digging further this way...